# Can you use a local `storage` value after it is deleted from a mapping or array?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage, mapping, memory

In Solidity, if you delete a value from a mapping or shorten an array, are local `storage` references to the deleted item still valid?

Case 1:

```
contract Case1 {
    mapping(uint256 => Widget) private widgets;

    function delete(uint256 key) {
        Widget storage deletedItem = widgets[key];
        delete widgets[key];
        // Is deletedItem zeroed out here?
    }
}
```

Case 2:

```
contract Case2 {
    Widget[] private widgetList;

    function getLast(uint256 key) {
        Widget storage lastItem = widgetList[widgetList.length - 1];
        widgetList.length--;
        // Is lastItem zeroed out here?
    }
}
```

Case 3:

```
contract Case3 {
    Widget[] private widgetList;

    function getLast(uint256 key) {
        Widget storage lastItem = widgetList[--widgetList.length];
        // Is lastItem zeroed out here?
    }
}
```

If these values are all zeroed out, what is the solution? To declare `Widget memory` rather than `Widget storage`, forcing a copy?

Comment: Just deleted my answer, I made a mistake and it's just wrong. I will update it later today when I have more time.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 and 2 are zeroed out, case 3 simply cannot work, I'll explain why.

### Case 1:

see the documentation about [delete](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html?highlight=delete#delete).

"delete a assigns the initial value for the type to a. I.e. for integers it is equivalent to a = 0"

This is because deletedItem is in storage and the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/types.html?highlight=storage#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour) states that :

"Assignments from storage to a local storage variable also only assign a reference."

So, `deletedItem` is a reference to `widgets[key]` that gets deleted (zeroed out).

If you were to declare `deletedItem` in `memory` you could use the previous value since "Assignments between storage and memory (or from calldata) always create an independent copy."

You can try the following code in Remix and see that it is indeed 0 after deleting the mapping element.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Case1 {

    struct Test { uint256 value; }

    mapping(address => Test) public myMapping;

    event myEvent(uint256);

    function testCase1() public {

        myMapping[msg.sender] = Test({value: 10});

        // Get a local storage reference to myMapping[msg.sender]
        // This is a REFERENCE
        Test storage deletedItem = myMapping[msg.sender];

        // Emit : 10
        emit myEvent(deletedItem.value);

        // Delete myMapping[msg.sender] : set to 0
        // deletedItem is a reference, so it is "also" set to 0
        delete myMapping[msg.sender];

        // Emit : 0
        emit myEvent(deletedItem.value);
    }
}
```

### Case 2:

In solidity >= 0.6.0, [`array.length` is read only](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/060-breaking-changes.html#explicitness-requirements) and the [`array.pop()`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html?highlight=pop#array-members) function is the only way to remove one element from the array (it automatically calls delete on it).

Basically on an array `pop()` does the following :

```
delete myArray[myArray.length - 1]; // The relevant 0 value for your type
myArray.length = myArray.length - 1;
```

Prior to 0.6.0, substracting from `myArray.length` did an implicit delete as shown [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.17/types.html#array-members).

"Reducing the length performs an implicit delete on each of the removed elements."

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Case2 {
     struct Test { uint256 value; }

     Test[] public myArray;

     event myEvent(uint256);

    function testCase2() public {
        myArray.push(Test({value: 10}));

        // Get a local storage reference to myArray[myArray.length - 1]
        // This is a REFERENCE
        Test storage lastItem = myArray[myArray.length - 1];

        // Emit : 10
        emit myEvent(lastItem.value);
        
        // Substract 1 to myArray.length AND delete value : set to 0
        // lastItem is a reference, so it is "also" set to 0
        myArray.length--;

        // Emit : 0
        emit myEvent(lastItem.value);
    }
}
```

### Case 3:

This last case cannot work.

```
Widget storage lastItem = widgetList[--widgetList.length];
```

Will modify `widgetList.length` in place and return the new value.

With an array containing N element, the last valid index is N - 1. So when writing `--widgetList.length` the size of the array is now N - 1, meaning that the last valid index is N - 2 (assuming it's still >= 0).

But the returning value is N - 1, which is an out of range index for the array.

---

> If these values are all zeroed out, what is the solution? To declare
> Widget memory rather than Widget storage, forcing a copy?

Exactly.