# Are storage values copied or referenced?

Tags: solidity, storage, memory, storage-pointer

Given this contract

```
contract C {
    struct Product { uint price }
    Product[] storage products;

    function doSomething() {
        products.push(Product({price: 100}));
        products.push(Product({price: 200}));
        products[0] = products[1];
        products[1].price = 300;
    }
}
```

Is the final price of `products[0]` 200 or 300?

(As a followup n00b question, how can I run a single function like this in Solidity so that I can see what the result is, without launching the contract on the blockchain?)

Answer (score 2):

> Is the final price of products[0] 200 or 300?

It is `200` because assignment from storage to storage always creates a copy as you can see [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/types.html?highlight=storage#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour).

"All other assignments to storage always copy. Examples for this case are assignments to state variables or to members of local variables of storage struct type, even if the local variable itself is just a reference."

As the other answer pointed out, the easiest way to test code is probably Remix.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please also weigh in on this related question?

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114621/can-you-use-a-local-storage-value-after-it-is-deleted-from-a-mapping-or-array

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ethereum Remix to test your contract without deploying it: https://remix.ethereum.org

Testing it on Remix it seems the values of arrays are not referencing:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract C {
    // correct syntax
    struct Product { 
        uint price;
    }
    // 'products' is declared as contract property,
    // thus it's already a state variable
    // no need to make it 'storage'
    Product[] products;

    function doSomething() public {
        products.push(Product({price: 100}));
        products.push(Product({price: 200}));
        products[0] = products[1];
        products[1].price = 300;
    }

    // for _index = 0 it will return price 200
    // for _index = 1 it will return price 300
    function getProductAtIndex(uint _index) public view returns(Product memory) {
        return products[_index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! Can you please also weigh in on this related question?

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114621/can-you-use-a-local-storage-value-after-it-is-deleted-from-a-mapping-or-array